# How to find out Azure blob storage container size in Visual Studio with Azure SDK installed?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-storage

I have installed Azure SDK into my Visual Studio 2012 and in the Server Explorer, I can connect to my storage account and [view all the various storage spaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683677.aspx), blobs, containers etc.

One piece of information I would like to find is **what is the size of one of my containers**. Is it possible within VS or do I need to use another tool? Maybe I am just overlooking some button or context menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess only way to get the size of the container is to loop through the blobs. I have checked with Azure storage explorer and Cloud Storage studio for the same but even these tools doesn't provide total size of the container but tells the size of each blob though.
Please see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f10a7a08-f787-4749-8220-5e19362bbef3/howto-containers-size-details-and-performance-)

Comment: If you're using Cerebrata's Cloud Storage Studio, you can right click on the container and click on `Container Statistics` menu item to see the total size of the container. But the approach there is to loop through blobs as mentioned by @Sandy.